# Random value when inserting in MYSQL server

Tags: php, mysql, sql, int

For some reason, when I insert  '2015041200000000' into an INT(20) field I turns into '2147483647'...

How is this possible?

I'm doing this because I want to format the auto incremented ID to YYYYMMDDXXXXXXXX with php.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2147483647 is far from a "random value". It's the maximum value of a signed 32-bit integer, so an INT data type is not enough to store the value you're trying to use. You may want to try BIGINT instead.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2147483647#In_computing
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/integer-types.html

Comment: Ah, I should have known that. More so because nothing is truly random when programming. It worked perfectly.

Comment: One more question, is this a good way to generate transaction id's? 

Having an auto increment field and then pulling the insert id and formatting that and reinserting it?