# Weird auto increment issue

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am making a transaction table with an auto increment field of `BIGINT(20)`.

When a new transaction is added, the insert Id is retrieved and formatted to be more readable:

```
public function add_transaction($paymethod, $cursus_id)
{
    $this->load->model('Config_model');

    $btw = $this->Config_model->get('transactions.btw');

    $query = "  INSERT INTO transacties(userid, paymethod, amount, btw_pc) 
                VALUES((SELECT userid FROM users WHERE lcase(username)=lcase('{$this->session->userdata('username')}')), 
                        '{$paymethod}',
                        (SELECT prijs FROM p_cursus_uitvoering WHERE uitvoering_id = {$cursus_id}),
                        {$btw});";

    $this->db->query($query);
    $insertId = $this->db->insert_id();

    $newCode = date('Ymd') . str_pad($insertId, 8, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);

    $this->db->where('transact_id', $insertId);
    $this->db->update('transacties', ['transact_id' => $newCode]);

    return $newCode;
}
```

The result is that the ID get updated from eg: 5 to 2015041800000005.

This is working perfectly, but as you can see, the newCode is returned in the function and used by another function where it's reinserted in another table.

Here is where the problem arises, the ID turns into: 201504192058506757.

Even when I echo the `newCode`, it still prints 201504192058506757.. even though it is inserted correctly once, but incorrectly the second time!

EDIT:

Here is the code snippet in which the function is called:

```
public function workshop(){
    $this->load->model('Inschrijven_model');
    $paymethod = $this->input->post("paymethod");
    //eigenlijk uitvoering_id.....
    $cursus_id = $this->input->post("cursus_id");
    if($paymethod == null || $cursus_id == null){
        redirect('cursus');
    }
    if($this->Inschrijven_model->cursus_has_room($cursus_id)){
        if(!$this->Inschrijven_model->cursus_ingeschreven($cursus_id)){
            $this->load->model('Cc_payment_model');
            $this->load->model('Cursus_model');
            $amount = $this->Cursus_model->get_price($cursus_id);

            $orderId = $this->Cc_payment_model->add_transaction($paymethod, $cursus_id);
            $this->Inschrijven_model->cursus_inschrijven($cursus_id,$orderId);


            $function = explode('_',$paymethod);
            $this->{$function[0]}($function[1], $amount, $orderId);

        }else{
            echo "Al ingeschreven";
        }
    }else{
        echo "geen ruimte";
    }
}
```

And here is the code snippet in which the return `$newCode` is being reinserted:

```
public function cursus_inschrijven($cursus_id,$transaction_id){
    $query = "  INSERT INTO p_cursus_in(uitvoering_id, userid, transact_id)
                VALUES({$cursus_id},(SELECT userid FROM users WHERE lcase(username)=lcase('{$this->session->userdata('username')}')),{$transaction_id})";
    $this->db->query($query);
}
```

It is reinserted so I can make a connection between someone's registration into a class and their payment for that class.

Comment: Aside: I wonder if you might have a SQL injection in `$paymethod` there. Can you use parameter binding? (I guess this is CodeIgniter - might be worth tagging appropriately?)

Comment: `but as you can see, the newCode is returned in the function and used by another function where it's reinserted in another table.` - I don't see where it's reinserted into another table. Probably a good idea to put the code with a problem in the question. (i.e. please do that).

Comment: This function is only called by other functions, would it still be necessary to use a parameterized query?

Comment: (Unrelated: `BIGINT(20)` is unnecessary. Look at the number. Your table will never ever even fill `INT(10)`.)

Comment: I used `INT(11)` before that and it would not work, another user on stack overflow suggested `BIGINT(20)` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29591181/random-value-when-inserting-in-mysql-server

Comment: If you are sure user input cannot get into the query, then you can get away without parameterisation. Personally, I find parameterisation so straightforward, I use it wherever possible.

Comment: What framework are you using?

Comment: I'm using codeigniter

Answer (score 1):

You have to convert the BIGINT to string before you get it into PHP

Here's how you can convert it with a SQL statement:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/cast-functions.html#function_convert

I don't know what framework you're using but you have to do a conversion if you're using BIGINT whose length is not supported by PHP directly. It seems that the framework will read the record after updated to check if the operation's done successfully, and because of the process of reading without the conversion, you got a wrong number.

You can also use PHP GMP module to handle BIGINT:
https://php.net/manual/en/book.gmp.php

Comment: Oh wow! Could you give an example on how I would cast it as something else? And is it necessary on both the select AND inserts? And is this a decent strategy or would you advice something else?

Comment: @NathanPrins It's wired that I can't reproduce the problem using mysqli or PDO with mysqlnd. Here my PHP will convert the value to string when selecting/inserting from/to database automatically. Are you using a PHP compiled with libmysql instead of mysqlnd? Could you please try the queries with pure mysqli and PDO to see if the problem is caused by the framework or the mysql client?

Comment: Is it possible to help me via skype or something? I'm really stuck on this.. It's slowing everything down :(

Comment: @NathanPrins Could you please firstly tell me what MySQL client you're using and the result of pure mysqli and PDO as I suggested? FYI, I found a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16374568/php-mysql-bigint-issue

Comment: I've 'solved' it by inserting the `newCode` into a different field `varchar(255)` field in both tables. Not how I initially wanted it, but it doesn't seem to have any drawbacks.

Comment: @NathanPrins Congratulations. But by the way, you'd better use `char(20)` for this case. Varchar may be saved un-continuously on your disk so it will slow your queries down a lot if you use it as an index (unless you use SSD).

Comment: Aaah thanks, that'd be smart. I should look into making everything a bit more efficient. Not that it's an incredibly large project, but it's good practice.